# Why do I no longer receive any security updates?

Tags: updates, security

I haven't received any security updates this past week. How do I check in terminal if everything is updating correctly?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? The last post on [USN](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/) was on 10th. Did you receive that update?

Comment: you cand do `sudo apt-get update && upgrade` to do so

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't gotten back sooner to answer your solution. I have done sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade but when I did the update it came back with the following line and I don't know how to implement the download.......   http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_12.04/ and this.....  Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.opensuse.org_repositories_isv:_ownCloud:_community_xUbuntu%5f12.04_Packages)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS sorry for the confusion but thanks for all the help I've received so far.

Comment: I should have posted the whole message as follows to be more clear, I apologize...... Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_12.04/  Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.opensuse.org_repositories_isv:_ownCloud:_community_xUbuntu%5f12.04_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

should show you enough of the noise to reassure you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't precise which version you are using, check on this image if your version is still supported :

[image]

To get information about packages supported, you can use this command:

```
ubuntu-support-status
```

Use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to manually check for updates.

Hopefully, sometimes nothing to do because nothing to correct :)

Comment: **Note :** If you have non-supported package with command `ubuntu-support-status`, it can be "normal" cause of universe repository (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu), which means  Community maintained software, not officially supported software.